# session not created: This version > of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 85

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Estoy haciendo unas pruebas automáticas con Selenium y a la hora de querer ejecutar una prueba, me sale este error en la línea de

```
Variables_RW.driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

El error que me sale es el siguiente:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'session not created: This version
> of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 85 (SessionNotCreated)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución fue buscar el chromedriver según la versión de Gogle Chrome aquí: [chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html)

Y a nivel de código, se hace lo siguiente:

> IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("Ubicación en el ordenador donde
> se descargó el driver")